# IDLE can't find cv2, CLI Python imports it correctly

Tags: python, opencv, command-line-interface, python-idle

I am able to import the OpenCV python bindings (cv2) fine when running Python from the command line, but I receive the standard 'no module named cv2' from IDLE when I import there.

I checked the Path Browser in IDLE, and noticed that it doesn't match my .bashrc PYTHONPATH.

That said, I copied the cv2 binding files into one of the directories specified in the Path Browser, and IDLE still can't find it.

Two questions:
1) Has anyone run into this circumstance?
2) Does IDLE have a PYTHONPATH different from the rest of the system?

Comment: What platform?  How are you launching IDLE?  Which version of python and IDLE?  In both the command line Python and in IDLE's shell, what are the results of: `import sys; print(sys.executable)`?

Comment: osX 10.7, launching IDLE from the dock as an application. Python 2.7.5, IDLE 2.7.5.

sys.executable returns
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch GUI applications on OS X (`.app` bundles), no shell is involved and shell profile scripts are not used.  `IDLE.app` is no exception.  So any environment variables defined there are not available to the GUI app.  The best solution is to properly install your third-party packages into the standard locations included in Python's module search path, viewable as `sys.path`, and not use `PYTHONPATH` at all.  Another option in this case is to launch IDLE from a terminal session shell, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/idle2.7`.

Comment: I didn't know that about shell vs. .app, answer accepted! The cv bindings do exist on my sys.path, but still no launching though. I want to do some more investigating and hopefully ask a more focused question later.